ElasticBeanstalk - The following instances have not responded in the allowed command timeout time
Iam trying to deploy my application in aws beanstalk which i have dockerized properly and i created an environment for it's deployment but when i try to deploy my application i get the following logs and deployment fails, when i try to request logs it says failed to retrieve logs.
May 1, 2024 00:30:12 (UTC+5:45) INFO Environment health has transitioned from Warning to No Data. None of the instances are sending data.  
May 1, 2024 00:28:13 (UTC+5:45) INFO requestEnvironmentInfo is starting.  
May 1, 2024 00:28:13 (UTC+5:45) WARN Environment health has transitioned from Info to Warning. Application update is aborting (running for 15 minutes). None of the instances are sending data.  
May 1, 2024 00:27:11 (UTC+5:45) ERROR During an aborted deployment, some instances may have deployed the new application version. To ensure all instances are running the same version, re-deploy the appropriate application version.  
May 1, 2024 00:27:11 (UTC+5:45) ERROR Failed to deploy application.  
May 1, 2024 00:27:11 (UTC+5:45) ERROR Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-08207a90dfcd27f39'. Aborting the operation.  
May 1, 2024 00:27:11 (UTC+5:45) INFO Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: \[Successful: 0, TimedOut: 1\].  
May 1, 2024 00:27:11 (UTC+5:45) WARN The following instances have not responded in the allowed command timeout time (they might still finish eventually on their own): \[i-08207a90dfcd27f39\].  
May 1, 2024 00:16:14 (UTC+5:45) INFO Environment health has transitioned from Ok to Info. Application update in progress on 1 instance. 0 out of 1 instance completed (running for 3 minutes). None of the instances are sending data.  
May 1, 2024 00:13:07 (UTC+5:45) INFO Deploying new version to instance(s).  
May 1, 2024 00:12:44 (UTC+5:45) INFO Environment update is starting.  
May 1, 2024 00:03:15 (UTC+5:45) INFO Added instance \[i-08207a90dfcd27f39\] to your environment. May 1, 2024 00:03:15 (UTC+5:45) INFO Environment health has transitioned from Pending to Ok. Initialization completed 9 seconds ago and took 2 minutes.  
May 1, 2024 00:03:06 (UTC+5:45) INFO Successfully launched environment: Ecommerce-microservice-env  
May 1, 2024 00:03:04 (UTC+5:45) INFO Application available at Ecommerce-microservice-env.eba-fegjshix.ap-south-1.elasticbeanstalk.com.  
May 1, 2024 00:02:59 (UTC+5:45) INFO Instance deployment completed successfully.  
May 1, 2024 00:01:52 (UTC+5:45) INFO Waiting for EC2 instances to launch. This may take a few minutes.  
May 1, 2024 00:01:36 (UTC+5:45) INFO Created EIP: 43.204.118.11  
May 1, 2024 00:01:21 (UTC+5:45) INFO Created security group named: sg-0e4d88fcccaf16670  
May 1, 2024 00:01:15 (UTC+5:45) INFO Environment health has transitioned to Pending. Initialization in progress (running for 11 seconds). There are no instances.

Please go easy on me, iam new to beanstalk.
I tried to deploy my dockerized application on it, the code runs fine on my local device but when i try to deploy on my aws beanstalk. I get that error

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Download logs for your environment and look for obvious problems. You can download logs from the AWS UI.
